# How do Magformers work

Tags: electromagnetism

https://www.magformers.com/

They are magnetic shapes.

The corners of shapes where the magnetic material is  seem to be attracted to both North and South (I have tested them on bar magnets) and yet they attract other magformers and ferromagnetic materials so please explain how they are magnetically structured?

Comment: The polarity of Magformers is explained in this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mv_8TvBug2A). The idea is that each side of Magformer has a magnet that rotates to align itself to the magnetic field.

Comment: @ atarasenko I think you should post that comment as an answer

Comment: You should do so quick so I can award you the bounty